# Javascript Browser executes code out of order

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, closures, form-data

I have a very large object, which turns into a very very very large JSON string.

I have an on click listener

```
randomElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("should log immediately");
    var content = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(veryLargeJson));
});
```

veryLargeJson is declared/updated outside the eventListener scope.

For whatever reason when I click on the element, the browser spinner comes up, as it attempts to stringify the veryLargeJson and then encode it, but this happens before logging in the console.

What in the world is going on here? why is the browser performing JSON.stringify out of order.

My first thought is that maybe the way event listener closures or closures in general work is that the variable declarations just get executed first , or all variables are resolved before anything else occurs. For example if my very large json was declared in a scope outside of the one that generated the click then immediately the browser tries to resolve what the very large json is, and in doing so freezes up because the json is so large, then goes ahead and prints out my console log, and only after that does it assign it to the local variable i declared in the listener.

Is this what is happening?

UPDATE-------------------------------------------------------------------

I have left the above question for context only.

This issue occurs specifically when there is a formData object in the event listener closure and an ajax request is being made with the very large json string being appended to the formData object.

**So my question is now, why does the closure evaluate the xhttp.send parameters out of order?**

```
randomElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("should log immediately");
    var content = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(veryLargeJson));
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("whatever", content);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://randomEndpoint", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    xhttp.send(formData);
});
```

Comment: why do you stringify a json? json is a string. and what is _browser spinner_?

Comment: It's a json object. Browser spinner is something that happens when the browser is doing a lot of work and wants to stop the user from clicking or simply wants to alert the user that the browser is working

Comment: A JavaScript Object Notation object? Please [read a little bit more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON) about the terms you are using.

Comment: @LorenShqipognja, okay, so it's simple JavaScript object, as I understand. And you want it to have represented in JSON. Correct? _Browser spinner is something that happens when the browser is doing a lot of work_ - can you attach a screenshot of that? I've never seen native browser spinners. And maybe you can create a plunker to demonstrate the problem. You wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Maximus the fact that it's a JSON i believe is irrelevant, i've narrowed down the issue to occurring when just sending a very large string as a formData object payload via ajax. Really I just want to know why it tries to convert the javascript object into a string before my log statement (out of order) Will try to provide a plunker but will be hard to replicate the large string I am sending

Comment: with `console.log` you tell the js environment (in this case the browser)  to log something. The time when this log is displayed in the gui - when it actually appears in the console - depends on the implementation and might be internally queued. The stringification of your object obviously blocks the whole browser (spinning wheel)  and as of that also delays the *display* of the debug message. But that does not change the fact that the `console.log` is executed before the `JSON.stringify(veryLargeJson)`.

Comment: @t.niese I tried this in debugger also on chrome however. The browser blocks before I step past the console.log statement

Answer (score 1):

The browser doesn't do processing "out of order". Unless web workers are in the game all processing is done in event handlers and single-threaded.

What may happen is that you **observe** the console log appearing after the `stringify` call, but still it was done before.

When it appears visible to you depends on the GUI event loop of the browser and normally GUI updates are just queued events and therefore they must wait for the clicked event to complete processing (unless you start a nested event loop - something that in Javascript happens only with `alert` and friends).

If you add a `console.log(+ new Date())` before and after the `stringify` call you will notice the long time required by the operation.

Comment: You are correct sir. The xhttp.send call was causing the browser to hang because of the heavy payload. After changing what initially was xhttp.open("POST", "randomEndpoint", false); to true , I was able to see my log statement whilst the post call was being performed and before it returned.